# Why weren't any sanctions imposed on India for not signing the Treaty on the Non-Proliferation of Nuclear Weapons?

Tags: international-relations, india, nuclear-weapons, sanctions

Why weren't any sanctions imposed on India for not signing the Treaty on the Non-Proliferation of Nuclear Weapons?

Comment: More context please: why are you asking about India, and hasn’t India received sanctions in the past for conducting nuclear tests?

Comment: Recently sanctions were imposed on North Korea. So just wanted to know what were imposed on India

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is North Korea criticized for having Nuclear Weapons?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/19130/why-is-north-korea-criticized-for-having-nuclear-weapons)

Comment: @Brythan: I don't think this is a duplicate, although may be related.

Comment: @adithskv DPRK [_did_ sign the non-proliferation treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_the_Non-Proliferation_of_Nuclear_Weapons#North_Korea). And then developed nuclear weapons anyway while lying about it. That's rather different from simply not signing it in the first place.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An entire international body designed for restricting trade of nuclear materials was created in response to India's first test, and **the US did impose sanctions on India for their tests in the 90's.** The reason India specifically hasn't been punished much is because they otherwise have a good nuclear record and claim to want stronger non-proliferation treaties.

---

**Nuclear Suppliers Group:** The [NSG is an export control group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_Suppliers_Group) which was created directly in response to India's first nuclear test, the amazingly named [Smiling Buddha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smiling_Buddha). The NSG is tasked with tracking and controlling materials that can be used to directly or indirectly create nuclear weapons. Since this certainly would have stopped imports of [certain items](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zangger_Committee) controlled by the NSG, you can say that India(and many other nations) received sanctions indirectly.

In regards to India's nuclear tests in the 1990's, [the US strongly condemned India and imposed pretty strict sanctions on them in 1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pokhran-II#United_States). In the following years, the US held talks with India regarding their nuclear program, though were unsuccessful in convincing India to reverse their program fully.

**India's Nuclear Record:** As was explained [in an answer to a similar question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/19130/why-is-north-korea-criticized-for-having-nuclear-weapons/24698#24698), the situation in India is different that in other nuclear-possible countries, such as North Korea, since they have  essentially adhered to the treaty since their tests. In the early 2000's, India and the US began working on an agreement which would allow India to begin working with the US to develop nuclear energy, with [a good part of the rationale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India%E2%80%93United_States_Civil_Nuclear_Agreement#Rationale_behind_the_agreement) being that India has 'de facto' status as a non-proliferation nation.

Essentially, India's polcies regarding no-first-use of the weapons, lack of apparent desire to create a large stockpile, and [claims](https://web.archive.org/web/20120112151514/http://www.whereincity.com/news/3/15197) that they want to sign a stronger version of the NPT meant that other nations didn't see much need to sanction or otherwise punish India for their weapons program.

Comment: India has nuclear material smuggling problem going on for quite some time now... http://indianexpress.com/article/india/india-news-india/atomic-material-smuggling-racket-busted-rajasthan-ats-arrests-six/

Comment: India police seize 8 lbs of uranium from smugglers ... https://www.reuters.com/article/us-india-uranium/india-police-seize-8-lbs-of-uranium-from-smugglers-idUSB65928720080219

Answer (score 9):

There were sanctions imposed on India in response to India conducting its first successful nuclear test.  [Article here (from 1998) reported the announcement](http://edition.cnn.com/WORLD/asiapcf/9805/13/india.us/).

Comment: Additionally, these sactions were lifted by the U.S. following India's support of the U.S. in the wake of the 9/11 attacks.

Answer (score 5):

I think all the answers so far are ignoring the herd of elephants in the room: India* is not a threat to anyone, India has a decent human rights record, India is unlikely to supply nuclear weapons or technology to jihadists, &c.

*Feel free to substitue Israel in this if you like.

Comment: `India is not a threat to anyone` -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_intervention_in_the_Sri_Lankan_Civil_War

Comment: `India has a decent human rights record` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_rights_in_India#By_state

Comment: `India is unlikely to supply nuclear weapons or technology to jihadists` - don't need to ... https://www.reuters.com/article/us-india-uranium/india-police-seize-8-lbs-of-uranium-from-smugglers-idUSB65928720080219

Comment: `India is not a threat to anyone` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Nepal_blockade

Comment: @why: 1) Re human rights, I said decent, not perfect.  2) Re threats, both your links seem to be as much about India protecting itself from spillover violence in neighboring countries.  3) Independent smugglers are not the same as state actors.

Comment: you haven't checked the links well. India's Sri Lanka fiasco is India's own fault, I can say this because I know this part of the history better than you do. You are welcome to study as well. Smuggling means, India's nuclear assets are not well protected which is a concern for international community.

Comment: It isn't a threat because no country imports crude oil from India.

Comment: @Mazura, No country also imports oil from North Korea.

Comment: The last sentence was a joke, right?

Comment: @why: Re Sri Lanka, I'm afraid I don't see your point.  Sri Lanka had an ethnic/religious-based rebellion, which threatened to spill over into India: "... the LTTE’s dream of a sovereign Tamil Eelam comprising all the Tamil inhibited areas (of Sri Lanka and India) posed a threat to India’s territorial integrity..."  So India was trying to deal with a perceived threat to itself, no?  Whether it mishandled its intervention is a separate issue.

Comment: @polfosol: Wrong.

Comment: @jamesqf, No. There was no chance of spilling. Indian Tamil community and politicians pressed the government to get involved in the conflict. Their interpretation was: being the mother country for Tamils, India should protect ethnic Tamils in Jaffna. That was a kind of Turkish invasion of Cyprus. By the way Raziv Gandhi was beaten by Sinhalese (a Lankan navy soldier) and killed by Tamils.

Comment: _Israel is not a threat to anyone, Israel has a decent human rights record, Israel is unlikely to supply nuclear weapons_. They look like three "not so funny" jokes.

Answer (score 4):

> Why weren't any sanctions imposed on India for not signing the Treaty on the Non-Proliferation of Nuclear Weapons?

This is an absurd question.

If some one is slapped by sanction for not signing a treaty, then why broach that treaty in the first place?

A sanction can be imposed for not abiding by the rules of the treaty while being a signatory. But, that is also too far fetched. Partners of that treaty can only expel that signatory, nothing else.

Comment: Is there evidence fairness or free-choice are meaningful forces in international relations?

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt, NATO alliance, WTO, etc.

Comment: I was being kinda factious; being nice is nice, and lots of governments like foreign aid, anti war crimes and corruption stuff, and NPT probably does fit in with them, but there certainly are also treaties and organizations made to promote some interests above others. And I would have put NATO and the WTO right at the top of that list.

Answer (score 3):

India, Pakistan obtained their nuclear weapons in Cold War period. Pakistan is strictly backed by U.S. India have close ties with U.S. because, from U.S. point of view, it is some sort of counter-weight against China.

Also, some another reason not to do it - there is arguments for it, Pakistan have nuclear weapons, and have tensions with India, so India do it for defense.

So, answer is:

- in Cold War U.S. and USSR have many other things to do, without these sanctions.
- it have rather close ties with U.S.
- North Korea example is full analogic, despite the fact, that North Korea do NOT have close ties with U.S.

There is also such complex question as Israel nuclear weapons, but it is much more custom situation, hardly comparable with India/Pakistan/North Korea examples

Comment: OK but why don't other countries compel India, Pakistan or Israel to sign the treaty?

Comment: I think this is like WW2 results - it is unspeakable. Nuclear weapons already exists. And about "other countries" - this should be strong countries, but Russia/China/U.S won't do it  - they all have good or better relations with India. And who other want to oppose them?

Comment: There is a known Golda Meir phrase "We do not have nuclear weapons, but we'll use it if there will be need". For nowadays it is one of "secrets that are widely known" in fact.

Comment: @adithskv Israel is deliberately vague as to whether it has nuclear weapons, and if so for how long. That isn't very compatible with the articles of the Treaty on the Non-Proliferation of Nuclear Weapons.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you're right. Will edit my answer

Comment: North Korea signed the NPT and then repudiated it.  Israel, India, and Pakistan never signed.

Comment: Question is "for not signing". Not for "repudiating"